# Unable to resolve instance from autofac when constructor requires a `Func<string>`

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to resolve an instance from autofac which requires a `Func<string>` as constructor argument.

constructor:

```
        public GitRepositoryFactory(
            IGitCommands gitCommands, 
            Func<string> repositoryUrlRetriever)
        {
            _gitCommands = gitCommands;
            _repositoryUrlRetriever = repositoryUrlRetriever;
        }
```

My registration:

```
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule<GitModule>();
            
            builder.RegisterType<GitRepositoryFactory>().As<IGitRepositoryFactory>().WithParameter(
                new TypedParameter(typeof(string), "https://bitbucket/scm/cmr/413.git"));
```

The exception on resolving:

```
  ----> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException : None of the constructors found on type 'IAI.Common.Utilities.Git.GitRepositoryFactory' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.Func`1[System.String] repositoryUrlRetriever' of constructor 'Void .ctor(IAI.Common.Utilities.Git.IGitCommands, System.Func`1[System.String])'.
```

What am I missing here? The string should be resolvable through the typed parameter I supplied?

Answer (score 1):

Argh, after years of using autofac I am still learning I guess. For anybody else struggling with the same, turns out I **can** register a func, but I need to explictly supply the `Func` as object.

I tried

```
    builder.RegisterType<GitRepositoryFactory>().As<IGitRepositoryFactory>().WithParameter(
        new TypedParameter(typeof(Func<string>), () => "https://bitbucket/scm/cmr/413.git"));
```

which doesn't compile, but when I explictly instantiate the object as `Func` it works fine...

```
    builder.RegisterType<GitRepositoryFactory>().As<IGitRepositoryFactory>().WithParameter(
        new TypedParameter(typeof(Func<string>), new Func<string>(() => "https://bitbucket/scm/cmr/413.git")));
```